# Is it better to put Facebook Connect on homepage or on Login/Registration pages and why?

Tags: usability, facebook-connect

I want to know if facebook connect button should be glaring at users straight from the homepage, or only at the login and register pages when users actually need to login or signup?

What does each of the two choices bring in as a plus and minus to the table?

Comment: Is Facebook used only for login on your site?

Comment: in short, you should add that option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your goal? There are obviously pros and cons of doing it either way. I say do BOTH.

General internet users hate creating a new login and they definitely hate being led down the process of signing up when all they wanted to do was comment on something or share it with Facebook.

Putting Facebook Connect button your homepage, if done tastefully and without creating more visual clutter, would increase sharing/tracking because it is a method that doesn't require much additional work for your users. It is familiar (unlike your site for most first time users, I'm assuming); it is something they are probably used before.

Putting Facebook Connect at the login or register point is also a good idea because it gives them another option that making a new account.

If you are looking for a good design pattern to follow, look at Goodreads.com.

Answer (score 1):

Vega is guiding you in right direction.

To add to it, users love to have options available at their desire wherever they are in the application. This makes the users feel that they have a way to get their task done, from wherever they are.

Similarly its good to have FB Connect on login. If the user does not choose that path and later wishes to share some content on FB the share button should give them options to share via (FB,Twitter..) (Options at their desire).

User should also be able to remove the used account (unlink accounts) probably in your settings. This gives the user confidence that he can easily link and unlink the accounts in your application, making him feel secure of using his social credentials.

Answer (score 0):

A short answer: Yes.
With a very valid reason.Your users are not getting to an actionable item on the homepage.The action happens after login (unless that assumption is not true in your case). Facebook connect is just another way of signing-in. Adding that option for a later stage is creating another round of clickable actions before the *actual action*.

In order to avoid a huge facebook connect button, using a drop down with the sign-up would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I've found [this](http://blog.mailchimp.com/social-login-buttons-arent-worth-it/) blog post very inspiring.

In general I suggest to encourage the users to sign up with you and maintain the control over your users.